# MySQL\bin is in my cmd: prompt. But it is not working - Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql

[image]Trying to install Rails on my Windows 8.1 computer.   MySql installed properly.   the >Path includes bin location      C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin

It is not the first item listed, which is the way I have it in the My Computer Properties, Advanced Settings, Environment Variables.

When I go to the MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\  folder and execute MySQL --version, it works... but no where else.

This is the case whether I am in the plain Command Prompt,   or in the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails.  (which print out a different paths from the prompt>Path)

It appears I have 3 path variables...   but none of them are working for MySQL.   The path appears to be working when I type   >rails server

What do I do now?

Comment: Often after changing environment variables, you have to restart the `explorer.exe` service or restart the computer. Have you tried this?

Comment: I just restarted my computer... but get the same results.   Thanks for the suggestion.   Is there a way to post a screen shot of the cmd windows showing the different paths?

Comment: yah, as long as you have the screenshots, there should be an image button that will allow you to upload a file.

Comment: close all command prompts, add c:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.1\bin to your path (old dos style) ,run command prompt and try again.

Comment: Fixed !  The problem was 2 fold.  Thanks James and Houssam for your responses... got me going on the right track.     1) MySQL was installed in Program Files, NOT Program Files (x86)... so corrected the path.     2)  The folder names with spaces I had to put in quotes...   "Program Files"  and "MySQL Server 5.1".      Also, to change the path in the Cmd prompt for Ruby and Rails, I had to add the correct path to the end of the setup_environment.bat file.    did that, and restarted my computer and wha-la... it works.